# override virtual function - derived classes have different parameters

Tags: c++, ooad

Let's say we have the following 2 classes

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void op(string& s1) = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(string& s1) override;
};
```

so far, so good. Now, a new requirement comes which necessitates
creating of Derived2 class, however this class needs 2 strings
as args in the op virtual function. Of course, if I add function op
with 2 strings as inputs in Derived2, it is overloaded not overriden.
So, I have to do something like -

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void op(string& s1) {}
    virtual void op(string& s1, string& s2) {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(string& s1) override;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(string& s1, string& s2) override;
};
```

This works, but I was forced to add the 2nd op function in Base class.
Also, the Base class functions are now not pure virtual, this is
necessary otherwise Derived classes would need to implement unnecesary
op functions. This seems kind of kludgy to me.

Now if a new requirement causes us to create Derived3, one with a 
different set of parameters for op function, we need to add one more
op function in the Base class. Ideally base class should not change if
someone adds a new derived class.

I am sure there is a better way to do this. Pretty certain there is a
design pattern for this, since this seems to be a common problem and
must have been already solved.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Amarnath

Comment: But why you are using inheritance at all if there is no common functionality between Base, Derived1 and Derived2

Comment: It contradicts the main idea of polymorphism. Base class must describe the common interface for all its derivatives.

Comment: The op function is the common functionality between 3 classes. The objects of derived classes are created and kept in a map. The value in the map is "Base*". When a certain event happens, we retrieve the object from the map and call base->op(). The base pointer here can point to any of the derived classes. The code calling base->op knows which derived class we are referring to and hence knows whether to pass 1 string, 2 strings or some other set of parameters.

Comment: @AmarnathShanbhag In this case, there are no need to make `op` function `virtual` at all. You need virtual function only if somebody calls it from `Base` pointer.

Comment: Careful with `override`, don't use it when you don't mean to override anything.  A new function name would be sensible.

Comment: Is the only reason you use inheritance here that you need to store things of a different types in a vector? Because then you might be better off with a `variant<Type1, Type2>` where `Type1` and `Type2` don't need to share a common base

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple derived classes doesn't "behave" the same (e.g. having different number of arguments for different derived classes), you have two choices (with some variations):

1. Implement the virtual functions in the base class for all of the variants.
2. Your class hieararchy isn't "clean", and you probably need to "know" which type it is in some cases. Use `dynamic_cast` (or your own type detection mechanisms, as in the LLVM project, which has `llvm::dyn_cast`)

Consider this:

```
vector<Base*> v;

... insert derived types in v ... 

for(auto i : v)
{
    v->op( ??? ) 
}
```

How does the code know if `op` is 1, 2 or 3 arguments? It can't, right? So your choice is to interrogate the class as to how many arguemnts `op` takes, have it take the same number always (e.g. `op("abc", "", "");` would be used for `Derived1`, `op("abc", "def", "");` for `Derived2`, and `op("abc", "def", "ghi");` for `Derived3`).

Or you could have something like:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void op(string& s1) = 0;
    virtual void op(string& s1, string &s2) = 0;
    ... for as many string arguments you need ...
    virtual int num_strings() { return 0; }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(string& s1) override;
    virtual int num_strings() override { return 1; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(string& s1, string& s2) override;
    virtual int num_strings() override { return 2; }
};
```

Now we can implement our generic(-ish) loop:

```
for(auto i : v)
{
    switch(v->num_strings())
    {
    case 1:
        v->op(s1);
        break;
    case 2:
        v->op(s1, s2);
        break;
    default:
        ... some handling of unknown number ....
    }
}
```

The key here is that if you are to "do" the same thing to all objecst derived from the same base class, they HAVE to have the same interfaces available.

In a compiler project I have, I use `llvm::dyn_cast`, when required, as the base class has a number of generic operations, but not ALL operations are available on ALL derived classes, because that would make the base class have a HUGE number of member functions that are completely useless - an `if` doesn't have to have the same operatios available as a `for` loop, and an assignment needs none of the things that either an `if` or a `for` loop needs.

Edit: Whilst preparing myself to get on with the day, I thought of another solution, that MAY be right in some cases: use a `op(vector<string>& sv)` instead of 1, 2, 3 or n arguments.

As with many things, the right solution is not always clear without further understanding of the exact problem.

Comment: In my case the code which is calling base->op knows which derived object we are dealing with and hence knows exactly how many args to pass. So, the num_strings function is not needed. In your code above the 2 op functions in base are pure virtual. So, this will cause Derived1 class to not compile unless it adds an empty op function which accepts 2 args. All this does not seem clean. Main concern is that we need to add a new op function to base class when we add a new derived class.

Comment: None of these solutions are particularly "clean", as it's not a clean interface if you have multiple variants of the same function - that's just how it is. If you ALWAYS know the derived type and number of arguments, why does it need to be a virtual function in the first place? Maybe that's where you are going wrong?

Comment: The code creating the object stores the object in a map. map<key, Base*>. In reality the value in this map will be pointer to either Derived1 or Derived2. An async event happens which retrieves the base object from the map and calls base->op() to signal that the event happened. Depending on the event, I know which derived object this is. I can cast the base pointer to derived (downcast) and then calling the derived->op() with correct number of args. In this case op function need not be virtual. However, I am trying a way to get rid of the downcast.

Comment: Casting in this particular case is not technically WRONG, although not very neat (and if there are MANY choices, not . Implementing a single, generic function that takes 2 or three argument (or a `vector` of arguments, or a `struct` or something like that), some of which may not be used is another. The KEY point is that if you don't want to cast [and have conditions in the "do something with the `map<key, Base*>` - which is never a neat thing], then a single virtual function that matches all use-cases is your answer.

Comment: @AmarnathShanbhag why do you have to downcast your pointer when your base class has alle the overloaded virtual functions defined anyway? But in your case casting is not a bad solution, why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @xander I was contemplating a soln of getting rid of the virtual function and going with the downcast approach.

Comment: @AmarnathShanbhag Why not just have different maps for different objects (`map<key, Derived1>`, `map<key, Derived2>`). There will be no need to downcast and you already know which map to look into when the event happens. If there is a need for a new op() with different parameters, you can add a 3rd map for the new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Taking cue from Mats answer and utilizing c++ initializer list constructor correct approach could be (note braces {} while calling op functon) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() { };
    virtual void op(const std::vector<string>& s1) {std::cout<<"Base..."<<s1.at(0)<<std::endl;}
   // virtual void op(const stdstring& s1, const string& s2) {std::cout<<"Base..."<<s1<<" "<<s2<<std::endl;}
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(const std::vector<string>& s1) override {std::cout<<"Derived1..."<<s1.at(0)<<std::endl;}
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual void op(const std::vector<string>& s1) {std::cout<<"Derived2..."<<s1.at(0)<<std::endl;}
};
int main()
{
    Base *ptr= new Derived2();
    ptr->op({std::string("Test1"),std::string("Test2")});

}
```